# Удаление пробелов через итератор Python

Tags: python

Не понимаю как удалить все пробелы в rev, пробовал через кортежи и списки, не получается. Удаление пробелов должно происходить в методах класса.

```py
class Reverse:
    """Итератор для переворачивания последовательности"""

    def __init__(self, data):  # инициализация 
        self.data = data  # переменной задается значение параметра
        self.index = len(data)  # определяем длину параметра

    def __iter__(self):  # включаем итерационный процесс
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.index == 0:  # если длина == 0
            raise StopIteration  # вызов исключения, останавливающего итерацию
        self.index = self.index - 1  # если не равна, то индекс уменшаем на единицу
        return self.data[self.index]  # и возвращаем предыдущий элемент


rev = Reverse('А роза упала на лапу Азора')
for char in rev:
    print(char)  # каждый вывод дает следующий (с конца) элемент
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Измените в `__init__` если в дальнейшем вам не нужна оригинальная строка:

```py
self.data = data.replace(" ","")
self.index = len(self.data)
```

Ну, либо добавить метод:

```py
def clear_from_spaces(self):
  self.data = data.replace(" ", "")
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):line 19, in <module>
    for char in rev:
    line 15, in __next__
    return self.data[self.index]  # и возвращаем предыдущий элемент
IndexError: string index out of range


data.replace('',' ') - работает,
data.replace(' ','') - а так нет

Comment: я думаю, что все таки выход за пределы обусловлен неправильным определением длины строки, я подправил ответ, проверьте

Comment: Да, упустил момент, спасибо за помощь!